# How to handle data type wise XML to JSON conversion by using NewtonSoft

Tags: json, xml, types, json.net

I am using NewtonSoft namespace to convert the xml data to json. I want the json data value to preserve the data type. But, by using "SerializeXmlNode" it is giving json data value in string.
XML Data is:

```
<statecode>1</statecode>
<iskit>false</iskit>
<name>PokeMon go</name>
<ExpirationDate>2013-12-31T00:00:00</ExpirationDate>
<price>25.00</price>
```

I am using the following code:

```
 string requestData = @"<products><statecode>1</statecode>
 <iskit>false</iskit>
 <name>PokeMon go</name>
 <ExpirationDate>2013-12-31T00:00:00</ExpirationDate>
 <price>25.00</price></products>";
     XmlDocument transformData = new XmlDocument();
     transformData.LoadXml(requestData);
     foreach(XmlNode data in transformData.GetElementsByTagName("products"))
     {
         string transformedJsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(data);
     }
```

Output:

```
{ 
    "statecode" : "1",
    "iskit" : "false",
    "name":"PokeMon go",
    "ExpirationDate":"2013-12-31T00:00:00",
    "price":"25.00"
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{ 
    "statecode" : 1,
    "iskit" : false,
    "name":"PokeMon go",
    "ExpirationDate":"2013-12-31T00:00:00",
    "price": 25.00
}
```

You can observe output is in string.